# ¿Como puedo hacer un moño hueco con asteriscos?

Tags: c++

Me han dejado una tarea de programación para hacer figuras con asteriscos, al intentar hacer un moño completo me ha funcionado, pero al querer hacerlo hueco se me hizo imposible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int dimension = 9;
char simbolo = '*';
    for (int i = -dimension/2; i <= dimension/2; i++)
    {
     for (int j = -dimension/2; j <= dimension/2; j++)
                        {
                            if (i*i <= j*j) cout << simbolo<<" ";
                            else cout << "  ";
                        }
                        cout << endl;
                    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las coordenadas de los asteriscos son:

> ```
> [0,0]                                   [8,0]
> [0,1][1,1]                         [7,1][8,1]
> [0,2]     [2,2]               [6,2]     [8,2]
> [0,3]          [3,3]     [5,3]          [8,3]
> [0,4]               [4,4]               [8,4]
> [0,5]          [3,5]     [5,5]          [8,5]
> [0,6]     [2,6]               [6,6]     [8,6]
> [0,7][1,7]                         [7,7][8,7]
> [0,8]                                   [8,8]
> ```

Si te fijas, la diagonal descendente es cuando ambas coordenadas son la misma, la ascendente cuando ambas coordenadas suman 8, la primera vertical cuando `x` es cero y la última cuando `x` es ocho. Por lo tanto, cuando se cumple cualquiera de esas condiciones hay que poner un asterisco:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int y = 0; y != 9; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x != 9; ++x)
        {
            if (x == y)
                std::cout << "* ";
            else if ((x + y) == 8)
                std::cout << "* ";
            else if (x == 0 || x == 8)
                std::cout << "* ";
            else
                std::cout << "  ";
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LCoMwEEXXma@Y2kW1UnDZ@uiXdCMxloBGiREi1W9PJwotlC6czcA95w4M7/sLb0r1dO4oFW/GSmAuu8FoUbZ3AKkMtqVUYQQvYHWnMfTRhAUmGa1DgbcM43iKgJHwNexm2I9hyVgVJmsMCRfoSzSDqdKUd6PBPMfgjEHmY9EMAr1KbkyqL1x3FdbbCc4z2l2lPxg3vAD8kNNDnYgswLQwo1b0IyzOvQE)</kbd>.

Comment: No soy el que hace la pregunta, pero he aprendido con esta publicación. Es útil. Tiene un merecido voto.

Comment: Guao!!!.........